# How to apply log on negative values based upon some conditions in python

Tags: python, math

I know that we can't calculate negative value in log.
I use math.log(number) to calculate log of any positive number.

I want to calculate the value of any number (let's say X) based upon the following conditions.

[image]

What is the efficient way to find any value for any number X (including negative, positive, and 0) based upon the above conditions in Python?

Thanks

Comment: You will need to check the condition for `X = 0` anyway, I don't think there's a convenient branchless formula for that.

Answer (score 2):

You can use multiple if statements to find the state of the variable you want to take the log of, then run the log based on the state of the variable:

```
def findlog(x):
    if x > 0:
        log = math.log(x)
    elif x < 0:
        log = math.log(x*-1)*-1
    elif x == 0:
        log = 0
    return log
```

Comment: Shouldn't be `elif x == 0:` in place of `elif x = 0:`?

Comment: Thanks for the answer :) I have values in a pandas data frame, do I need to iterate over every value and check conditions or any trick through which I do it in just single line? Thanks :)

Comment: You can use df.apply(findlog) to apply the function to each value in the dataframe

Comment: Ok, got it. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```py
import math
def my_log(x):
    abs_x = abs(x)
    return ( (x//abs_x) * math.log(abs_x) if (x) else x)
```